# htaccess redirect issue

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have the following on my .htaccess file within /var/www/html folder.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.net [nc,or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.au [nc,or]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent, NC, L]
```

I want all domain.net and domain.com.au requests to redirect to domain.com.

This does not seem to redirect. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If it helps, the server is on Amazon ec2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've had trouble with spaces in the list of flags. Also, the last OR is not needed and may cause problems. Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with that!

Comment: If you go to the other domains (.net, .com.au) are the results the same as going to www.domain.com? Are you certain .htaccess overrides are enabled with e.g. `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: I get this error on error_log, [alert] /var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: I've never seen `[R=permanent]` before.  Only `[R=301]`.

Comment: Sorry! I had spaces in mine [R=permanent, NC, L], changed to [R=permanent,NC,L]. Now it works GREAT!